# How to create a newCountDataSet using DESeq

Tags: r, data-structures, bioinformatics

I have a table, here's the start:

```
TargetID         SM_H1462   SM_H1463    SM_K1566    SM_X1567    SM_V1568   SM_K1534     SM_K1570    SM_K1571    
ENSG00000000419.8   290 270 314 364 240 386 430 329     
ENSG00000000457.8   252 230 242 220 106 234 343 321 
ENSG00000000460.11  154 158 162 136 64  152 206  432
ENSG00000000938.7   20106   18664   19764   15640   19024   18508   45590   32113
```

I want to make a newCountDataSet object of of this table using the DESeq package.

Here's my code:

```
#First, define Control & Case so that condition can be defined later
#Here, the colnames are grouped into Control or Case based on their name (the SM_... ones)

my.df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(seq(1,8),3), ncol = 8))
colnames(my.df) <- c('SM_H1462','SM_H1463','SM_K1566','SM_X1567', 'SM_V1568', 'SM_K1534', 'SM_K1570','SM_K1571')
control = my.df[,(substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'H' | substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'K')]
case = my.df[,(substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'X' | substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'V')]

#Define condition
condition= c(control, case) 

cds1 = newCountDataSet(data, condition)
```

But I get thus error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I think it's because condition has to be a factor, and it's currently a list of 24. So I've tried

```
condition=factor(condition)
```

but I get the same error message.

Comment: I think you're using edgeR/DESeq? It's important to mention it... Not everybody knows the function.

Comment: Yes, I'm using DESeq!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used *DESeq* but according to `?newCountDataSet` `conditions` has to be a factor that length equals the number of columns in `countData`. The following should work:

```
condition <- factor(ifelse(substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'H' | substr(colnames(my.df),4,4) == 'K', "control", "case"))
cds1 <- newCountDataSet(my.df, condition)
```